# Calling NASM from a C program using system() produces different object code then calling using Bash

Tags: c++, assembly, linker, g++, nasm

I've implemented a reasonably good optimizing compiler (for a toy language), and have come across a rather puzzling scenario. I can take an input file and produce assembly from it, so in that respect the "compiler" is finished. If I take that assembly file assemble it with NASM and link it to my runtime support library with G++ (the runtime needs libstdc++), I get a working executable, with no errors. However, I'd like to be able to compile to an executable in one command, so I added some calls to `system` to my compiler, passing the EXACT SAME COMMANDS as I was using in bash. When I run the compiler, it seems to assembly properly, but the linking step (again, using g++) fails with an `undefined reference to main`. Confused, I attempted to link manually (without reassembling, so I was using the object file produced by the NASM run with `system`, and received the same error. If I reassemble using the new compiler's assembly output, I have no problems, which has led be to believe that NASM is the problem. Like I said, the commands are exactly the same (I literally copied and pasted them just to make sure after the first time). Is this environment variables or something? What's going on?

EDIT:
I manually assembled an object file, again using the same command as the one in the compiler, and I did a vim diff between the two. The compiler-generated one seems to only contain the ELF header.

EDIT 2:
A screenshot of the diff[image: screenshot]

EDIT 3:
I tried using `system` to call a Perl script that in turn would call NASM and G++, still no luck.

Comment: Thanks. I try to refrain from asking here until I've been stumped for a few days of constant searching :P

Comment: What about environment variables, is it possible the GCC reads from them?

Comment: That's actually what I'm thinking, only with NASM instead of GCC (I pretty much isolated it as the source of the problem, see above)

Comment: What options are you using with nasm?

Comment: Only -f elf and specifying an output file with -o. EDIT: I am running a 32 bit OS.

Comment: @chameco Maybe a silly question, but no `NASMENV` environment variable set in the shell?

Comment: Nope. In fact, I'm starting to get even MORE confused, because even if I move the file that I'm `%include`ing for macros, it throws the same error (in the linker), when in Bash it throws the expected "no such file" error. This makes no sense whatsoever, because I can delete the NASM generated object file and a new one will be generated. It's almost like NASM isn't being called at all if not for that variable.

Comment: More information added to the question.

Comment: Did you flush or close your ASM output file before calling `system`?

Comment: Yes, there is a call to `fclose`.

Comment: Does your compiler call nasm and the link step in rapid succession? Does the failure still happen if you throw in a five second sleep() in between?

Comment: Try replacing `nasm` step with `cat`. Do you see your code?

Comment: @Lol4t0, no I don't. So, potentially the file not being flushed?

Comment: @chameco, yes. May be file haven't been flushed yet, or you somehow trying to assemble wrong file (misspelled in path or smth like this). You can try adding delay after file is closed and assembling is started, if it won't fix the problem, check path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! It was the file not being flushed due to a race condition. Thanks for all the help, much appreciated.